# how to set up a library in Ubuntu 15.04 g++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I tried to use a library named curlpp. It is basically used for fetching various http webpages. It is based on the libcurl. I downloaded the library from curlpp official website. The downloaded package consists of various folder.
I have looked throughout several stackoverflow pages. But none explained how to set up a library for g++ in linux. If there was a webpage in stack overflow, please refer me to that site.

[image: Screenshot showing the contents of the curlpp package]

What are the procedures that I should follow?

Comment: “I have looked throughout several stackoverflow pages” Really? I googled “curlpp ubuntu” and the SO duplicate was the second result. The first result was the page of the Ubuntu curlpp package.

Answer (score 0):

The package comes with install instruction in a file called INSTALL.

1. extract the downloaded file
2. open a terminal inside that folder
3. Run these commands in sequence
   ./configure
   make
   make install

Comment: usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2